# How to make IntelliJ IDEA display colors for different occurrences in the side bars

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, highlight, text-editor, sidebar

When coding java in Eclipse, one can easily edit the right side bar (found in settings under General\Editors\Text Editors\Annotattions) to display colors for different kind of occurrences (such as *Text Occurrence*, *Write Occurrencies* and *Read Occurrencies*).

In IntelliJ IDEA, there seems to be a ruler/gutter-bar on the left side and on the right side we have something called the "Error stripe bar". I seem to be able to make some static colorings, like for example setting "Constructor declaration" green. This way all Constructor declarations are highlighted green in the "Error stripe bar". I can however not find any place on how to just hilight text occurrences, write-/read occurrences, overridings etc.

**In Eclipse, it is enough to just put the cursor on a variable and all write and read occurrences are displayed in the right bar (if highlighted).** This way it is easy to locate the variable and not including any partial search results (such as finding for "a" would include every and each "a" in the whole text)

**EDIT**

Highlighting "Search Results" in the error stripe bar is the closest I have come, but is not what I want. In the case of highlighting the search results, I have to perform an extra search, CTRL + F, but this is just a dummy-text-highligter. Also, there are three options:

1. Search result
2. Search result (write access)
3. Text search result

None of these does the trick.

Comment: There are "Search Result" and "Search result (write access)" color settings in "Settings | Editor | Color Scheme | general - Search results"

Comment: Yep, that is kind of the only thing I've found what comes to the highlighting. Anyway, this is not actually what I want. In the case of highlighting the search results, I have to perform an extra search, CTRL + F (which won't highlight write occurrences for a variable, for example). In Eclipse, it is enough to put just the mouse pointer on a variable and all write and read occurrences are displayed in the right bar. This way it is easy to locate the occurrences, instead of scrolling through the file

Answer (score 2):

After some extended researching and testing I found a solution.

In order to get dynamical highlighting, close to what Eclipse provides in terms of "Write Occurrences"/"Read Occurrences", go to:

*Settings -> Editor -> Color Scheme -> General*

Under the *Code* section, select ***Identifier under caret*** and ***Identifier under caret (write)***

I hope this may save some time for new IntelliJ IDEA developers coming from the Eclipse environment.

Comment: Okay, that is a good point. The first thing I did, as an Eclipse user, was to find a lighter theme. I should maybe add this to the answer.